# get date selected by user without timezone

Tags: javascript, json, date, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a few date fields in my form for which I am using `JqueryUI` `datepicker` for the user to select the date. The date should be displayed in `dd/mm/yy` format when the user selects a date. I am using `KnockoutJS` to manage data binding on client side and using the following `KO` binding handler for `JqueryUI` `datepicker`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' };
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");


        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Now when the user selects the date, it is displayed correctly in `dd/mm/yy` format in the `input` `text` field and a `javascript` `Date` object along with timezone is getting captured in the `KO` `observable`. I am using `ko.toJSON()` function to convert the entire complex `javascript object` which contains various date fields to a `JSON` string and deserializing it in the backend.

The problem I am facing is when the `javascript` `Date` object is converted to `JSON` string, it reduces one day from the user selected date which I am assuming is because of the local timezone and this is the default behaviour javascript date objects. I have also tried the `momentJs` library to get `UTC` date from the selected date using the following code but this doesn't seem to work:

```
moment.utc(selectedDateObject).toDate()
```

What I want is to get whatever date the user selected in the form using the datepicker without any time zones, plain and simple. How can I go about this? `Date` object seems to get unnecessarily complicated in javascript.

Comment: moment(selectedDateObject).format('L') - can this help you?

Comment: @titi23 this is not working...when I call `ko.toJSON()`, one day is reduced from the selected date...

Comment: Can you show some working code, as this way helping you is difficult. Have to tried using getUTCDate() of Javascript?

Comment: Second the previous comment; help us reproduce the issue step by step, so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override toJSON function of moment.

Please see [Moment Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) for more details, but basically you need to do something like this

```
moment.fn.toJSON = function () {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'); //Or any desired format
};
```